# Jspm SFX bundle for Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Is it possible in theory? 
I've tried with `jspm` 0.16 and 0.17 and `jspm build` command. The bundle gets produced but loading it fails in `aurelia-loader-default` with an error

```
aurelia-loader-default.js:160 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: require is not a function
    at DefaultLoader.loadModule (http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js:1466:9)
    at DefaultLoader.loadModule (http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js:1465:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js:554:25DefaultLoader.loadModule @ aurelia-loader-default.js:160DefaultLoader.loadModule @ aurelia-loader-default.js:157(anonymous function) @ aurelia-bootstrapper.js:85
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. The enhancement which is needed is tracked [here](https://github.com/aurelia/bundler/issues/147)